# 2001: There are duplicate files in AppManifest.xml in upload app to windows phone store

Tags: xml, windows-phone-8, windows-store-apps

Validation errors

2001: There are duplicate files in AppManifest.xml. Remove one of the files and then try again. 2001: There are duplicate files in AppManifest.xml. Remove one of the files and then try again.

when i try to upload the .xap file this error appear .
i try to rebuild and the same errors  appear 
this is my AppManifest.xml

```
    <Deployment xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/client/2007/deployment"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"> 
        <Deployment.Parts>
        </Deployment.Parts>
    </Deployment>
```

this is my AppManifest.xaml

```
<Deployment xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/client/2007/deployment" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" EntryPointAssembly="ZwgatElrasol" EntryPointType="ZwgatElrasol.App" RuntimeVersion="4.7.50308.0">
<Deployment.Parts>
<AssemblyPart x:Name="ZwgatElrasol" Source="ZwgatElrasol.dll" />
<AssemblyPart x:Name="Microsoft.Advertising.Mobile" Source="Microsoft.Advertising.Mobile.dll" />
<AssemblyPart x:Name="Microsoft.Advertising.Mobile.UI" Source="Microsoft.Advertising.Mobile.UI.dll" />
<AssemblyPart x:Name="microsoft.advertising.mobile.ui" Source="microsoft.advertising.mobile.ui.dll" />
<AssemblyPart x:Name="Microsoft.Phone.Controls" Source="Microsoft.Phone.Controls.dll" />
<AssemblyPart x:Name="Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Maps" Source="Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Maps.dll" />
<AssemblyPart x:Name="Microsoft.Advertising.Mobile" Source="Microsoft.Advertising.Mobile.dll" />
</Deployment.Parts>
</Deployment>
```

Comment: This is confusing, Which one is it? top one or bottom?

Comment: i think the error in the top

Comment: do you have 2 AppManifest.xml files in the project?

Comment: no one xml and the other xaml

Comment: You can't possibly have AppManifest.xml and .xaml files in a standard project unless you add one. Do you mean App.xaml file?

Comment: no i delete .xml file now i have the botton onely and the same problem occure

Comment: oh god, don;t delete the AppManifest.xml file under Properties section. It is necessary. Did you delete it? And did you add any packages using Nuget?

Comment: what Nuget ?? i'm not understand

Comment: Nuget is a [package manager](https://www.nuget.org/). Anyway did you add the code inside the `<Deployment.Parts> ... </Deployment.Parts>` tags?

Comment: i'm  not add any thing manually

Comment: you are trying to add AdController to your app ryt?

Comment: yes i try it but its'n worked

Comment: Take a look at the answer i just gave you another one of your questions :)

Comment: thanks it's work for test but about publish do you know what's the problem ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some how your project has `AppManifest.xaml` file in it. But it shouldn't be there.The values in your AppManiferst.xml is correct. Keep it as it is and remove the `AppManifest.xaml` file.

You are using AdControl and even if you add that reference to your project, those `AssemblyPart` tags shouldn't be in the `AppManifest.xaml` file. So remove the `AppManifest.xaml` and keep the `AppManifest.xml` file that is under your Properties section as it is.

If it still a mess, the best way for you is to create a new project and start over, add the references for the Advertising in to the References section and then add the AdController described in the other questions of yours, Don't make any changes to `AppManifest.xml` file.

You need to turn on some capabilities on the `WPAppManifest.xml` but do them using the designer provided. And if you have your ApplicationId and AdUnitId from the pubCenter,  include them and all should work correctly.

You can use other alternative such as AdDuplex to display ads when pubCenter ads are not available.

Comment: after resolving the error i find [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25104619/1001-we-werent-able-to-unpack-the-package-try-again-or-submit-a-different-one)   any help pls ?