# 1001: We weren't able to unpack the package. Try again or submit a different one.in upload app to windows phone store

Tags: windows-phone-8

i'm trying to upload my xap file but i'm getting an error:

Validation errors
1001: We weren't able to unpack the XAP. Try again or submit a different one.

does anyone here has any idea why i get this error ?
thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you change the Build Configuration from `Debug` to `Release` in the toolbar. I think that is the problem. You will find the proper XAP at ProjectName\Bin\Release.